# ModSecurity Whitelisting for specific uri

Tags: php, apache, security, centos

I have set up Apache2 + PHP5 on CentOS 7

Some PHPs of my web application, they accept UUID as GET parameter and this violates the ModSecurity URI pattern.

I want to set up ModSecurity to bypass security checks for specific URIs.
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an exclusion rule like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@endsWith /dir/script.php" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=932130;ARGS:get_or_post_parameter,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941100;ARGS:get_or_post_parameter,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=932130;ARGS:get_or_post_parameter2"
```

Set your URI in the first line and, at the end of the rule, add exclusions for pairs of rule ID and GET/POST parameter name (like in the example above). Finally, put rule into file REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf .

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you!